# Which of these queries is better (more efficient)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Which of these 2 queries is better optimized:

```
SELECT 
    item.id, 
    dbo.fnCalculatePurchasePrice(item.id, 0, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) AS cost
FROM 
    Item item
```

or

```
SELECT 
    item.id, a.cost
FROM
    Item item
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
         dbo.fnCalculatePurchasePrice(item.id, 0, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) AS cost) a
```

My opinion in that the first query is better because we only have simple selection. The second query has a more costly `CROSS APPLY` operation.

Comment: If the second one takes longer, then I think your answer is obvious. I'd look a way to achieve what you want without a function since they are usually costly.

Comment: @scsimon They both take the same time. But that may be due to internet issues while I execute one query and not the other, also the server is on another pc.

Comment: Can you post the function code?

Comment: Replacing your scalar function with an inline table valued function would be the best option...or doing the calculation in your query would be even faster but not always the best option if you need to reuse it.

Comment: It is not good practice to put a function as a SELECT column. Better to create a TBF to be joined.

Comment: @cloudsafe TBF?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry, typo - TVF

Comment: Ahh wasn't sure what you meant there. :)

Answer (score 3):

Both are similar for your case,since both queries are same.. you can see the same from execution plan

Below code executes per row

```
SELECT item.id, dbo.fnCalculatePurchasePrice(item.id, 0, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) AS cost
FROM Item item
```

one with cross apply also does the same..For every row in select cross apply is executed and  nulls are rejected

you could see the same from below demo..numbers table has over 70K rows

```
alter function dbo.sc
(
@val int
)
 returns int
as
begin
return @val
end

select * ,dbo.sc(number)
from numbers

select *
from
numbers n
cross apply
(select dbo.sc(number)) b(A)
```

now observe execution plan costs for both batches

[image]